# VisualVM hangs when installing plugins

Tags: visualvm

I'm trying to install some plugins for VisualVM but it keeps hanging on the below screen - telling me "Please wait until the installer discovers plugin dependencies". I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. It hangs both when I try and install them from the "available plugins" list and when I try to install them manually after downloading them from the [VisualVM plugins centre](https://visualvm.java.net/pluginscenters.html).

[image: Visual VM Screenshot]

Comment: Which version of VisualVM do you have in your Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: I'm using version 1.3.3

Comment: I see, I was able to install Visual GC and MBeans plugins into VisualVM 1.3.3 just fine. Are you behind the proxy? This looks like a proxy settings problem.

Comment: Hi Sorry for the delay in reply - I've had to switch to a Windows machine to use VisualVM. No I'm not behind a proxy.

Answer (score 3):

I have just got the same problem with visualvm 1.3.2 installed from default ubuntu repo.

It used opendjdk as default (configured in /usr/lib/visualvm/etc/visualvm.conf), it works after I switch to oracle jdk, for example, assuming you installed oracle jdk at /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_43

try

```
jvisualvm --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_43/
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 12.04, Visual VM 1.3.2.
Fixed the same issue by switching from OpenJDK 6 to OpenJDK 7.
`jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386"` in /usr/lib/visualvm/etc/visualvm.conf.